why printf can not print string of a pointer?
I write this program for print content of a string in c language.
but dont print string!
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#define GROW_BY 10
int main(){
    char *ptr_s;
    int c;
    ptr_s= (char *) malloc(GROW_BY);

      printf("please enter a string\n");
     while((c=getchar() ) !='\n'){
         *ptr_s++=c;
     }
     *ptr_s=0;
     printf("the string is : \n %s \n", ptr_s);
}

result is :
the string is: 
do not print content of string in ptr_s.
where is problem?

You need to use the original value of ptr_s.  You increment it each time you add a new character, so at the end, it points to the null character at the end.  Just look at the last two lines of main.  It sets the pointer target to zero, then prints it.  That's an empty string.  Make a copy of the original pointer value, and try passing that pointer to printf.

the problem is use of original value of ptr_s in increment
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#define GROW_BY 10
int main(){
    char *ptr_s, *copy_ptrs;
    int c;
    ptr_s= (char *) malloc(GROW_BY);
    copy_ptrs=ptr_s;

      printf("please enter a string\n");
     while((c=getchar() ) !='\n'){
         *copy_ptrs++=c;
     }
     *copy_ptrs=0;
     printf("the string is : \n %s \n", ptr_s);
}

